# ASP.NET Core 2 all users password reset as admin

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm looking for a possibility to reset the password for all users in a database. Is it anyhow possible? All I have found so far, was about enabling password reset for the user himself, but it's not that I need.

I need to force old user to recreate a password for our app. Maybe there are some better solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the password", exactly? Do you want to ignore decades of security research and best practices and reset _all_ user's passwords to "Welcome123" and mail that to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do a global password reset, what you should do is create a function that generates random cryptographically secure passwords and simply change each user's password to those random ones (not just one, generate a password for each user). This essentially causes a global lockout, since no user will then be able to login, since they won't know this password.

Afterwards, you should send an mass email indicating that passwords have been reset and directing users to your password reset page. They'll essentially just act as if they've forgotten their password, and go through the normal process of submitting their email, clicking the link with a token in the email that gets sent, and then setting a new password.

You should also update your sign in failure message temporarily to indicate that all users must reset their password, so if someone misses the email, they'll know why their password isn't working and what they need to do to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I've ended with this solution and updating the database now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reset the password to something specific for all users, then you'd need to update the `asnetUsers` table with a hashed password and password salt for the new password.

From experience, the easiest way to do do this is the change the password using the app for a specific user, grab the `PasswordHash` and `PasswordSalt` from that changed user, and then run a SQL `UPDATE` on all other users with the same combination.

It's not exactly secure, but it will do the job.

More or less:

```
-- Update User using App, and get the ID
DECLARE @Id INT = XX -- Your app userid here
DECLARE @PasswordHash NVARCHAR(MAX), @PasswordSalt NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- get the password hash and salt for the changed user
SELECT @PasswordHash = PasswordHash, @PasswordSalt = PasswordSalt 
FROM aspnetUsers
WHERE Id = @Id

-- Update the other users with the same password and salt
UPDATE aspnetUsers SET
    PasswordHash = @PasswordHash,
    PasswordSalt = @PasswordSalt
WHERE
    Id IN (---whatever you need to filter by)
```

Comment: No problem. I realise that the accepted solution is a much better secure option. This is a quick a dirty version that we use on our testing and development databases. It works and it's quick and dirty. People should be aware of that before they apply it to a production envronment.